Why isn't the "button" part of my Vuetify radio button visible?
I have the following code in my App.vue file:
v-radio-group(inline v-model="mode")
  v-radio(label="Find distance" value="two")
  v-radio(label="Find station" value="calc")


The label displays fine, but the circle of the radio button doesn't display.
I have no CSS affecting radio buttons as far as I can tell (a decent chunk of my code for this project has been copy and pasted from another project). style.css is an empty file and this is the CSS at the bottom of the App.vue file.
<style>
.guess {
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  /* border: 1px solid grey; */
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
}

.breaker {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.textbox {
  margin: auto;
  /* padding-right: 20px; */
  width: 100%;
}

.guesses tr:first-child {
  background: hsl(60, 70%, 90%);
}

.guesses tr:first-child .guess {
  color: black !important;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
</style>

I've tried:

Commenting out all the CSS at the bottom of the file.
Adding a style="visibility:visible" to the v-radio and v-radio-group tag.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Most likely, you have not installed an icon font

Can you add the actual usage of template section?

Moritz Ringler thank you, that solved it!! Legend.

Thanks Moritz for the solution.
Copy and pasting this into my index.html  solved the issue.
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

